# SSIS 2008: Illegal characters in path when trying to rename a file

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, ssis-2008

I have a task that should rename a file

I have a variable called RenameFileName

```
\\servername\csv\BACKUP_" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + ".csv
```

When I run the task I get the error

```
Illegal characters in path
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I have tried escaping backslashes, and putting it quotes. If I remove the parts with brackets and pluses, it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: `\ ` characters need to be escaped.

Comment: I've tried that, I've tried encapsulating the whole thing in quotes as well - all 4 versions deliver same error

Answer (score -1):

As I mentioned, you need to escape the backslashes (`\` ). Also, you're missing a opening and closing double quote (`"`):

```
"\\\\servername\\csv\\BACKUP_" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + ".csv"
```